# Converting ECEF (XYZ) covariance matrix to ENU covariance matrix

Tags: coordinates, wgs84

How to convert the covariance matrix for the coordinates in ECEF and get the covariance matrix in ENU (local East North Up).

Any help is welcome,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the covariance matrix (Σenu) for East, Nort, Up. It is based on a given covariance matrix (Σxyz) for the geocentric coordinate increments in X, Y, Z. The law of propagation of variances gives:

[law of propagation of variances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMncK.png)

Where:

[F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1uCz.png)